# Convert paypal date to string in python

Tags: string, date, paypal

paypal is giving me this format '03:00:00 Mar 14, 2023 PDT'. I've tried different solutions but i can't get with the right one. How can i separate each item into a string using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a datetime object

```py
from datetime import datetime

time_string = "03:00:00 Mar 14, 2023 PDT"
d = datetime.strptime(time_string[:-4], "%H:%M:%S %b %d, %Y")
```

or

```py
import parsedatetime as pdt # $ pip3 install parsedatetime
cal = pdt.Calendar()

time_string = "03:00:00 Mar 14, 2023 PDT"
d = cal.parseDT(time_string)[0]
```

Once you have your datetime, output the part(s) you want using `strftime`